# jQuery not unchecking checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var number = [];
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    number.push($(this).val());
  });
  if (number.length == 0) {
    $('.category1').prop('checked', true);
    loaddata();
  } else if ($('#all').checked && number.length != 8) {
    alert('it executed');
    $('#all').attr('checked', false);
    loaddata();
  } else {
    loaddata();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="expander-list" id="category">
  <li>
    <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="all" class="category1">all</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="electronics" class="category1">Electronics</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="kitchen" class="category1">Kitchen</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="decoratives" class="category1">Decoratives / Interior</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="homedecor" class="category1">Home Decor</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="furnitures" class="category1">Furnitures</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="toys" class="category1">Toys</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="radio" style="padding-left:0px">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="vehicles" class="category1">Vehicles</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My concern is very simple. by clicking on all jQuery is selecting all checkboxes but if one of them are unchecked than all checkbox are must be uncheck. but it not unchecking to all checkbox even my else if condition is not executing and it not alerting me. How to resolve it and thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#all').checked` => `$('#all').is(':checked')`

Comment: Use `prop()` instead of `attr()` for "boolean" HTML attributes. Especially avoid a mix of both.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var unchecked_flag = false;

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').slice(1).each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
      unchecked_flag = true;
    }
  });

  if (unchecked_flag) {
    $("#all").prop("checked", false);
  } else {
    $("#all").prop("checked", true);
  }
});

$("#all").click(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w4yv02qb/)

Answer (score 1):

1. the statement `$('#all').checked` does not return what you expect.
   To get the `checked` property you need `$('#all').prop('checked')`
2. Watch out the difference between `.prop()` and `.attr()`.
   the first get the current `checked` property, the second will return the `checked` attribute (statically defined in the HTML page).
   Avoid using `.attr()` if you are looking for the current state of a checkbox.

Try with this snippet:

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
       var number = [];
       $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
          number.push($(this).val());
       });
       if (number.length == 0) {
          $('.category1').prop('checked', true);
          loaddata();
       } else if ($('#all').prop('checked') && number.length !== 8) {
          alert('it executed');
          $('#all').prop('checked', false);
          loaddata();
       } else {
          loaddata();
       }
    });
```

See also [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

Hello According to your requirements I think the below fiddle will solve your problem try this hope it helps you.

> I did it for both  "all" and "single" checkbox for your help.you can choose the task whatever you wish..

**your jquery will be something like below..

```
<script>
$("#all").change(function () {
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));       
});
$(".category1").click(function() {
if( $(this).prop("checked") == false)
{
$(".category1").attr("checked", false);
$("#all").attr("checked", false);
};
});
</script>
```

**Try the below Fiddle**

[Checkbox select Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ScnQT/2807/)